# 416 Error when creating url from a Blob

Tags: web-audio-api

I'm using the Web Audio API to record a stream of audio source nodes. My code looks like this:

```
var context,
    bufferLoader,
    destination,
    mediaRecorder,
    source,
    bufferList,  
    chunks = [],
    sound_paths = [],
    audioRecordings = [];

//fill in sound paths
sound_paths = ['sound.mp3', 'sound2.mp3'];

bufferLoader = new BufferLoader(
    context,
    sound_paths,
    callback
);

//fill bufferList with bufferdata
bufferLoader.load();

destination = context.CreateMediaStreamDestination();
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(destination);

mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e){
    chunks.push(e.data);
}

mediaRecorder.onstop = function (e) {
    var blob = new Blob(chunks, {'type': 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus'});
    var audio = document.createElement('audio');
    audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    audioRecordings.push(audio);

    chunks = [];
};

function startRecording(){
    mediaRecorder.start();
    source = Recorder.context.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = bufferList[0];
    source.connect(Recorder.destination);
}

function stopRecording(){
    mediaRecorder.stop();
}

//call startRecording(), then source.start(0) on user input
//call stopRecording(), then source.stop(0) on user input
```

I am using a the BufferLoader as defined here: http://middleearmedia.com/web-audio-api-bufferloader/

This works for the most part, but sometimes I get a 416 (Requested Range Not Satisfiable) when creating a Blob and creating a URL from it. This seems to happen more often when the web page begins to lag. I'm guessing this is because the Blob is undefined when creating the URL, or something like that. Is there a safer way to handle the onstop event for the media recorder? Maybe it would be better to use srcObjet and a MediaStream instead of a Blob?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my website http://gtube.de (just an example no commercial) i am using recorder.js=>https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs. It works very good. Perhaps you should give that a try to record the context.

If you load the mp3.s in buffers with the web audio api and play them just at the same time it will devinitely work. => https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/
But thats already the way you do it => The code is missing in your example above so i had to read the article => Perhaps next time you try to make a shorter example.

Sorry i don't know enough about mediaStream API => I suppose it's broken ;-)
If something in web-audio doesn't work just try another way. It is still not very stable => Especially the Mozilla people are  supporting it badly.